# Failed to get the handle of the Windows Internet Explorer main window

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, visual-c++, com, window-handles

**Background:**

I am creating a IWebBrowser2 and navigating to a URL. This is the short version of the code:

```
IWebBrowser2* pWebBrowser = NULL;
hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWebBrowser2, (void **)&pWebBrowser);
hr = pWebBrowser->Navigate(bstrURL, &varFlags, &varEmptyStr, &varEmptyStr, &varEmptyStr);
hr = pWebBrowser->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);
// Get the handle of the IE window 
HWND handle = NULL;
hr = pWebBrowser->get_HWND((long*)&handle); // this could be done better with reinterpret_cast
…
```

**Problem:**

Sometimes, the call to get_HWND fails with the 0x80004005 error code. It is failing only on some workstations.

**Questions:**

1. Why the call to get_HWND randomly fails?
2. Is the usage of get_HWND done correctly? The expected type is SHANDLE_PTR.

**Some links that might be useful:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752126%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://codecentrix.blogspot.com/2007/11/when-iwebbrowser2gethwnd-returns-efail.html

Need additional information? Just let me know

Thank you!

Comment: 0x80004005 is "Access Denied". No problem with your usage of get_HWND. There is something about your program vs security considerations for the failing workstations.

Comment: @manuell From what I gather, 0x80004005 is 'Unspecified error'. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx

Comment: You are right. Sorry. What happens if you call get_HWND earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to **get_HWND** is just fine and it randomly fails as the instance being killed. Why?

The call to **CoCreateInstance** with **CLSID_InternetExplorer** will instantiate a process with low integrity level. If the URL you navigate to is bound to a low integrity level (true for internet sites) there will be no problem. On the other hand, if you navigate to a URL that is bound to medium integrity level (true for intranet/trusted sites), then your process will be killed and a new process with medium integrity level will be created (seamlessly in IE8 and up). This operation is called a “Virtual Tab switch.”

### For more information about the problem and how to solve it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/03/internet-explorer-automation-protected-mode-lcie-default-integrity-level-medium.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Windows Internet Explorer 8. On Windows Vista, to create an instance
>   of Internet Explorer running at a medium integrity level, pass
>   CLSID_InternetExplorerMedium (defined in exdisp.idl) to
>   CoCreateInstance. The resulting InternetExplorerMedium object supports
>   the same events, methods, and properties as the InternetExplorer
>   object.

### You probably want to verify this is indeed the issues you are facing. Here is how to run a quick test:

1. Open IE
2. Go to settings
3. Security tab
4. Local intranet
5. Click the "Sites" button
6. Uncheck “automatically detect intranet network”

That should suppress the Virtual Tab switch

[image: Test IE integrity level]

### Here is an additional info about Protected Mode (taken from the book Pro Internet Explorer 8 & 9 Development: Developing Powerful Applications for the Next Generation of IE by Matthew Crowley):

> Windows Vista introduced the concept of MICs, which use integrity
>   levels (ILs) to differentiate filesystem objects, registry locations,
>   and APIs by trust and privilege levels and User Account Control (UAC)
>   to funnel elevation requests to users. This architecture helps to
>   protect system and user files against malicious access by untrusted
>   applications.
>
> The **integrity levels** present on Windows Vista and higher fall into
>   four major categories:
>
> **System**: Core operating system (NTAUTHORITY); system components, files, and data
>
> **High**: Machine-level access (administrators); program files and local machine registry hive
>
> **Medium**: User-level access (users); user files and settings and current user registry hive
>
> **Low**: Untrusted content, temporary files, and data